# NodeJS - Serve Resources Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed express using npm in VS. But i have **empty** exception in lines started with **app.use** in **server.js**:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css')));
app.use("/fonts", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'ttf')));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'png')));
app.use("/scripts", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js')));


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(loadCore());
}).listen(port);
```

I want to serve css, ttf, png, jpg and also just js files existed in **scripts** folder. How should i do this?

## Edit

I finally changed my server like this; i write it here in case might help anyone:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css')));
app.use("/fonts", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'fonts')));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images')));
app.use("/scripts", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'scripts')));

app.get('/',//to serve application
    function (req, res) {
        res.send(loadCore());
    }
);
app.get('/service',//to serve service
    function (req, res) {
        res.send("[SERVICE]");
    }
);
app.listen(port);
```

My *css* files is in **public/css** folder; i mapped it to **localhost:port/css/** using this:

```
app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss

```
var path = require('path');
```

somewhere at the beginning. Otherwise the `path` variable doesn't point to anything.

Similar issue will, however, occur with `loadCore` function that doesn't seem to be defined either.

Comment: Ok i added this line; there is no error but when i put the css address like **http://localhost:1337/css/index.css**, i cannot see the css file.

Comment: i defined **loadCore**.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, your answer helped me; i also changed resources usage to: **app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '', 'css')));**